# How can i remove duplicates only when they repeat themselves in the next iteration through pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

My question is a little bit confusing, so it's better to show what my input and output look like.
I've tried working on it for a bit but I'm reaching a dead end everytime.

Input:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | b |
| 5 | c |
| 6 | c |
| 7 | a |
| 8 | a |
| 9 | b |
| 10 | c |

Output:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 5 | c |
| 7 | a |
| 9 | b |
| 10 | c |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to groupby like `itertools.groupby` here. To do something like that in pandas check if next element is not equal to curr element. We can use [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) + [`pd.Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) + [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).

```
grps = df['B'].ne(df['B'].shift()).cumsum()
df.groupby(grps).first()

    A  B
B       
1   1  a
2   3  b
3   5  c
4   7  a
5   9  b
6  10  c
```